# horizontal lines in org mode tables

Tags: org-table, odt

I want to obtain in org mode tables something like `\cline` to limit horizontal lines. For example

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
$p$ & $q$ & $p \rightarrowq$ \\ \hline
0& 0& 1\\
0& 1& 1\\ \cline{1-2}
1& 0& 0\\
1& 1& 1\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

any idea?

Comment: Org mode tables do not support this capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not particular about using the `latex` backend, you can go with the `odt` backend, specifically the `*enhanced* ODT backend`.  Since the question is more about table grid lines than the math, I have removed the math snippets.

You need to use the [*enhanced* ODT exporter](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt) `ox-odt-9.5.3.467.tar` or later (or simply, any version whose date is *later* than June 14, 2022 IST).

**The *enhanced* ODT backend is not available with standard Emacs or Org mode, and you need to install it separately.  See [Getting Started with ODT export (OpenDocument Text Exporter for Emacs’ Org Mode](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Installation) for instructions.**

To get this

[image: A ODT Table with complex grid layout]

do this

```
#+odt_preferred_output_format: png
#+options: toc:nil
#+title: How to get custom rules in a ODT Table

To create this table

#+NAME: table-with-complex-cell-borders
#+CAPTION: A table with complex grid layout
#+ATTR_ODT: :rel-width 50
#+ATTR_ODT: :col-cookies "| c | c | c |"
#+ATTR_ODT: :suppress-spans t
#+ATTR_ODT: :span "@2$1{2:1} @2$2{2:1} @2$3{4:1}"
#+ATTR_ODT: :span "@4$1{2:1} @4$2{2:1}"
|-----+-----+-------------------|
| /p/ | /q/ | /p \rightarrow q/ |
|-----+-----+-------------------|
|   0 |   0 |                 1 |
|   0 |   1 |                 1 |
|-----+-----+-------------------|
|   1 |   0 |                 0 |
|   1 |   1 |                 1 |
|-----+-----+-------------------|

do this

#+NAME: raw-org-table
#+CAPTION: Org version of the preceding table\\
#+CAPTION: Pay attention to =ATTR_ODT= lines
#+ATTR_ODT: :category "table"
#+begin_src org
#+ATTR_ODT: :rel-width 50
#+ATTR_ODT: :col-cookies "| c | c | c |"
#+ATTR_ODT: :suppress-spans t
#+ATTR_ODT: :span "@2$1{2:1} @2$2{2:1} @2$3{4:1}"
#+ATTR_ODT: :span "@4$1{2:1} @4$2{2:1}"
|-----+-----+-------------------|
| /p/ | /q/ | /p \rightarrow q/ |
|-----+-----+-------------------|
|   0 |   0 |                 1 |
|   0 |   1 |                 1 |
|-----+-----+-------------------|
|   1 |   0 |                 0 |
|   1 |   1 |                 1 |
|-----+-----+-------------------|
#+end_src

* Explanation

=:span= attribute specifies a set of rectangles using
=@R$C{ROWSPAN:COLSPAN}= format.  When =:span= attribute is used with
=:suppress-spans t= attribute, you specify that you want to control
the table borders.

For example, in the Table [[raw-org-table]] above,

- the entry =@2$1{2:1}= says that the rectangle spanning =Row 2,
  Column 1= to =Row 3, Column 1=, a =2x1= rectangle has no /inner/
  borders, only /surrounding/ borders.

- the entry =@2$3{4:1}= says the rectangle spanning from =Row 2,
  Column 3= to =Row 5, Column 3=, a =4x1= rectangle will have no
  /inner borders/ but only /surrounding/ borders.

For ease of understanding, match the above description with what you
see in Table [[table-with-complex-cell-borders]].

#+ATTR_ODT: :target "extra_styles"
#+begin_src nxml :noweb yes :exports code  :eval never
<style:style style:name="OrgCode"
             style:family="text">
  <style:text-properties fo:background-color="#ffff00" fo:color="#000000"/>
</style:style>
#+end_src
```

### Explanation

Pay attention to the `ATTR_ODT` lines which specify `:span` attributes
and `:suppress-spans` attribute.

When `:span` attribute is used with `:suppress-spans t` attribute, you
specify that you want to control the table borders.

`:span` attribute contains a set of rectangles, and each rectangle is
designated in `@R$C{ROWSPAN:COLSPAN}` format.

For example, a `:span` entry of `@2$1{2:1}` says that the rectangle
spanning `Row 2, Column 1` to `Row 3, Column 1`, a `2x1` rectangle,
has no *inner* borders, but only *surrounding* borders.

Rectangles / cells that are *not* in a `:span`-set will get all the 4 borders-- *top*, *right*, *bottom* and *left*.  In a sense, the `:span` cells marks *"bigger"* rectangles, that are *"exeptions"*.

*(Note that the table grid lines in the example above are controlled by `ATTR_ODT` lines and not by the `hline`s and `vline`s in the Org table. In other words, even if you strip (or mangle) the `hline`s and `vline`s in above `org` table, you would still get the *same* grid layout)*